# Refactor code to not throw Mockito's UnnecessaryStubbingException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mockito, rx-java

I have a simple view with button that starts `Intent.ACTION_PICK` for result and than displays chosen contact on screen. To do that following steps must be taken:

- check if `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` is granted
- open contact activity
- select contact and go back to app
- check for `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` again
- find contact by given uri
- show contact on screen

I want to test scenario when one open contacts than revokes permission and goes back to app with selected contact. Expected result is not to call method that find contacts by its uri.

Unfortunately current implementation throws:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException:

for:

```
whenever(interactor.getContact(any())).thenReturn(Maybe.just(Contact()).doOnSuccess { find = true })
```

I know that I can replace `StrictStubs` with `Silent` but I'm looking for better solution with refactoring current code.

**All necessary class and test:**

```
class Contact

interface View {

    val contactClicks: Observable<Any>

    fun setContact(contact: Contact)
}

interface Interactor {

    fun getContact(uri: String): Maybe<Contact>
}

interface Router {

    fun goToContacts(): Maybe<String>
}

interface Permissioner {

    fun requestReadContacts(): Single<Boolean>
}

class Presenter(
        private val view: View,
        private val interactor: Interactor,
        private val router: Router,
        private val permissioner: Permissioner
) {

    private val disposables: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    fun bindView() {
        view.contactClicks
                .flatMapSingle { permissioner.requestReadContacts() } //ask first time before opening contacts
                .filter { it }
                .flatMapMaybe { router.goToContacts() }
                .flatMapMaybe {
                    permissioner.requestReadContacts() //ask second time before using ContentResolver
                            .filter { granted -> granted }
                            .flatMap { _ -> interactor.getContact(it) }
                }
                .subscribeBy { view.setContact(it) }
                .addTo(disposables)
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs::class)
class PresenterTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var view: View

    @Mock
    lateinit var router: Router

    @Mock
    lateinit var permissioner: Permissioner

    @Mock
    lateinit var interactor: Interactor

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var presenter: Presenter

    private val contactClickSubject = PublishSubject.create<Any>()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        whenever(view.contactClicks).thenReturn(contactClickSubject)
    }

    @Test
    fun shouldNotFindContactWhenReturnedWithUriAndPermissionNotGrantedSecondTime() {
        var firstTimeAsk = true
        whenever(permissioner.requestReadContacts()).thenReturn(Single.fromCallable {
            if (firstTimeAsk) {
                firstTimeAsk = false
                return@fromCallable true
            } else {
                return@fromCallable false
            }
        })
        whenever(router.goToContacts()).thenReturn(Maybe.just("contact"))
        var find = false
        whenever(interactor.getContact(any())).thenReturn(Maybe.just(Contact()).doOnSuccess { find = true })

        presenter.bindView()
        contactClickSubject.onNext(Any())

        assertFalse(find)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UnnecessaryStubbingException` means you are stubbing something, but not really using it. And that's correct, in your case `interactor.getContact` should be never called in test - this is desired behaviour. So there is no point in stubbing it.

The simplest solution would be to remove unnecessary variable `var find = false` and stubbing - substitute them with assertion at the end of your test:

```
verify(interactor, never()).getContact(any())
```

This is equivalent to your current solution but more straightforward than using helper variables.